# New SSD not seen by Ubuntu 16.04 in LiveCD mode or during install

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a brand new SSD, but the SSD is not being recognized.

I'm trying to perform the install on an Acer Aspire 5100. It's running PhoenixBIOS. The BIOS recognizes the SSD correctly as a PNY 120GB device. There aren't many options to set in the BIOS.

I've checked some other similar posts and the suggestions all point to using gparted to create a new partition or partition map, but gparted sees the DVD as the only SATA device. It doesn't matter if I'm trying to install or run Ubuntu as a LiveCD; the result is the same.

Unfortunately for me I'm new to Linux so I'm totally lost as to what to do without a suggestion. Any ideas as to how to get Ubuntu to see my SSD?

Thank you.

Comment: What mode is your HDD controller in?  (IDE, AHCI, RAID?)  If you put a regular HDD back in, does it get recognized by the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: The BIOS is very basic. It doesn't show any options. I'll have to see what happens if I put the original HDD back in. It's not at hand at the moment.

Comment: @Techie007 I checked the old drive. Ubuntu does see the old drive when I reinstalled it.I believe the first partion, /dev/sda1, is the DVD from which Ubuntu is booted.

Comment: @Techie007 I checked the old drive. Ubuntu does see the old drive when I reinstalled it.I believe the first partion, /dev/sda1, is the DVD from which Ubuntu is booted. The label is PQSERVICE. The size is 7.81 GiB. The flag is diag. The second partition, /dev/sda2, looks to be part of the HDD. The size is 52.14GiB. The flag is boot. The 3rd partition, /dev/sda3, is labeled DATA. The size is 51.84GiB. There is a 4th partition (?) that is unallocated with a size of 2.49GiB. I'm starting to wonder if the SSD was seated, but I would think that if it wasn't that the BIOS wouldn't have seen it.

Comment: Tried the SSD again, but no luck. I noticed that when I tried the original HDD I could see the boot and data partitions on the desktop. I don't see any partitions when I boot and the SSD is installed.

Comment: I tried installing Fedora 24 and had the same result. I saw on a forum a reference to the installer not knowing what to do with the SSD caching; it doesn't understand it, so it doesn't recognize it as a disk. It looks like I'm out of luck. :-(